# How to setup Windows XP on Dell Latitude E6400?

Tags: windows, windows-installation

I'm going to install Windows XP SP2 on my Latitude E6400 Dell Laptop. However, after I boot from cdrom the message appears:

> Windows is inspecting your hardware configuration

Then the black screen appears and it doesn't show any windows form.

Does anyone have idea or solution?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Dell Latitude E-series laptops come with IRRT set as their default SATA Operation which a non-dell XP installation cd cannot handle.

Boot into the BIOS (F12), select "System Configuration", "SATA Operation" and change it from "IRRT" to "ATA".

Comment: I've tried this already but it still doesn't work.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to "AHCI" Mode . That will sort your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to low level format dells first to install an OS.

plus xp doesn't recognize a sata hd unless the driver is slip streamed in.

Answer (score 0):

Download Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver (Intel_Rapid-Storage-Technolo_A04_R264761.exe), extract it, find its folder, and copy to a floppy disk using a USB floppy drive.
Make sure BIOS SATA Operation setting remains as IRRT.
XP CD will look for SATA driver from the USB floppy drive.